# How to consume messages from Kafka in Java, starting from a specific offset

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

reading from the earliest:

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
```

reading from the latest:

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
```

but what line should I use if I want to start for example: from 18th commit forward?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`seek()`](http://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#seek(org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition,%20long)) in order to force the consumer to start consuming from a specific *offset*:

> `public void seek(TopicPartition partition, long offset)`
>
> Overrides the fetch offsets that the consumer will use on the next `poll(timeout)`. If this API is invoked for the
> same partition more than once, the latest offset will be used on the
> next `poll()`. Note that you may lose data if this API is arbitrarily
> used in the middle of consumption, to reset the fetch offsets

---

For example, let's assume you want to start from offset `18`:

```java
TopicPartition topicPartition = new TopicPartition("myTopic", 0);
Long startOffset = 18L;
    
List<TopicPartition> topics = Arrays.asList(topicPartition);
consumer.assign(topics);
consumer.seek(topicPartition, startOffset);

// Then consume messages as normal..
```

Comment: Could it be that this only works when the `KafkaConsumer` is subscribed to the topic?